# Highlight a text from context angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am new to `AngularJs` . I want to highlight a text from a context . I have following code

```
        $scope.highlight = function(content, text, className, notByWordBoundry){
            var RegExpEscapeText, str;
            if (!(content && content.replace)) {
                return '';
            }
            if (!text) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
            }
            if (!className) {
                className = 'mark';
            }
              RegExpEscapeText = text.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
              if (!notByWordBoundry) {
                  str = new RegExp('(\\b)' + RegExpEscapeText + '(\\b)','gi');
              } else {
                  str = new RegExp(RegExpEscapeText,'gi');
              }
              return $sce.trustAsHtml(content.replace(str , '<span class=' + className + '>$&</span>'));
        };
```

So , My context contains data

```
a`bout any problems or issues  and worked on design/enhancement and architecture .Client- java,spring,Jquery,jqgrid,hibernate,Ajax,Jboss,Mysql,eclipse,jira, pmd etc.`
```

So , my code is working fine for all content . But I want to highlight `client-`.
   For this is not working .If I removed the regex and used "text" from the input to highlight , then It does not highlight's the proper word from the context .
For example -

```
Is word , I want to highlight , so  context is having Is word more than 3 times then whichever is the first gets highlighted . But I want to highlight the same word from the context .
```

can anyone help me with this ?

```
Here text is the value which is present in the context. I want to highlight that text.
```

Comment: If you pass `notByWordBoundry` as *true*, you should get the correct match. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO6zT1/1).

Comment: Yes , as a parameter i am passing value of notByWordBoundry as a false .

Comment: So, only `Client-` gets highighted, right? Sorry, you question does not sound very clear. A plunkr could be of help.

Comment: This is not specific for the client- . It's a dynamic . I am extracting some values from bakend . That extracted value is present in the context . I want to highlight that extracted value

Comment: Did you tried [mark.js](https://markjs.io)?

Comment: No I have not tried it. But I think i need to change my regular expression .So , can anyone help me in that  .